# Calculating per second peak values after summing up individual values in clickhouse

Tags: sql, replication, distributed, clickhouse

I am currently using Clickhouse cluster (2 shards, 2 replicas) to read transaction logs from my server. The log contains fields like timestamp, bytes delivered, ttms, etc. The structure of my table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE db.log_data_local ON CLUSTER '{cluster}' (
  timestamp DateTime,
  bytes UInt64,
  /*lots of other fields */
  ) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster}/db/tables/logs/{shard}','{replica}')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp
TTL timestamp + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;

CREATE TABLE db.log_data ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
AS cdn_data.http_access_data_local
ENGINE = Distributed('{cluster}','db','log_data_local',rand());
```

I am ingesting data from Kafka and using materialized view to populate this table. Now I need to calculate the peak throughput per second from this table. So basically I need to sum up the bytes field per second and then find the max value for a 5 minute period.

I tried using ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree with aggregate functions for the throughput, but the peak value I get is much less compared to the value I get when I directly query the raw table.

The problem is, while creating the material view to populate the peak values, querying the distributed table directly is not giving any results but if I query the local table then only partial data set is considered. I tried using an intermediary table to compute the per-second total and then to create the materialized but I faced the same issue.

This is the schema for my peaks table and the materialized view I am trying to create:

```
CREATE TABLE db.peak_metrics_5m_local ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
(
  timestamp DateTime,
  peak_throughput AggregateFunction(max,UInt64),
)
ENGINE=ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree('/clickhouse/{cluster}/db/tables/peak_metrics_5m_local/{shard}','{replica}')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(timestamp)
ORDER BY (timestamp)
TTL timestamp + toIntervalDay(90);


CREATE TABLE db.peak_metrics_5m ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
AS cdn_data.peak_metrics_5m_local
ENGINE = Distributed('{cluster}','db','peak_metrics_5m_local',rand());

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW db.peak_metrics_5m_mv ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
TO db.peak_metrics_5m_local
AS SELECT
        toStartOfFiveMinute(timestamp) as timestamp,
        maxState(bytes) as peak_throughput,
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            timestamp,
            sum(bytes) as bytes,
        FROM db.log_data_local
        GROUP BY timestamp
    )
    GROUP BY timestamp;
```

Please help me out with a solution to this.

Comment: *maxState(bytes)*8 as peak_throughput* looks pretty suspicious because multiplied AggregationState and number. Need to apply multiplication either in subquery where calculated a sum or outside. Or consider to use [SimpleAggregateFunction](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/simpleaggregatefunction/) instead of AggregateFunction.

Comment: Sorry. That was something I was trying out. Have edited the MV query now.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to implement with MV. MV is an insert trigger.

`sum(bytes) as bytes, ... GROUP BY timestamp` works against inserted buffer and does not read data from log_data_local table.

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/14266#issuecomment-684907869